# snap.svg: wrong origin point of rotation

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Hello I need to animate a vertical bar in order to do a vector based html metronome build upon SVG. I searched a lot to resolve my problem but I'm not able to do what I need.
I need to have a vertical bar (basically a rectangle) that rotate on his center bottom (highlighted by the red spot), like in this video (sorry I did it with Premiere and it is not as accurate as I wished, but I hope is clear enough):
[image]

But I always get a wrong rotation, the rotation involve also a translation and I don't know why, I'm afraid for my poor knowledge in snap svg (look at the snippet):

```js
var s = Snap("#svg");
var rect = s.rect(200,130, 40,200).attr({ stroke: '#FFFF00', 'strokeWidth': 3, fill: '#202070' });
var bbox = rect.getBBox();
var circle = s.circle(bbox.cx, bbox.y2, 10).attr({fill: 'red'});
rect.animate({  transform: "r45," + (bbox.cx) + ',' + (bbox.y2)   }, 2500);
```

```css
#svg {
    width : 400px ;
    height: 400px ;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://snapsvg.io/assets/js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in Snap 0.5.0+ when animating rotations that have centre coordinates.  If you drop back to the previous version (0.4.1), it works.

```js
var s = Snap("#svg");
var rect = s.rect(200,130, 40,200).attr({ stroke: '#FFFF00', 'strokeWidth': 3, fill: '#202070' });
var bbox = rect.getBBox();
var circle = s.circle(bbox.cx, bbox.y2, 10).attr({fill: 'red'});
rect.animate({  transform: "r45," + (bbox.cx) + ',' + (bbox.y2)   }, 2500);
```

```css
#svg {
    width : 400px ;
    height: 400px ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```

Comment: Seems to have [already reported](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/541). Sounds like it is fixed for 0.5.2.